# CSS radial gradients rule applies to all browsers but Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, radial-gradients

I am applying this CSS rule to some divs on a web application. Basically I need to display a border around the div, but without using the border property.
It works on every browser but Firefox. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), -moz-radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), -moz-radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px), -moz-radial-gradient(#dedede 1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 1px);
  background-position: top, right, bottom, left;
  background-size: 1px 1px, 1px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/za74L1st/1/

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a job for `linear-gradient` not `radial-gradient`.

```css
.box {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F8F9FA;
    background-image: 
      linear-gradient(#dedede,#dedede),
      linear-gradient(#dedede,#dedede),
      linear-gradient(#dedede,#dedede),
      linear-gradient(#dedede,#dedede);
    background-position: top, right, bottom, left;
    background-size: 100% 1px,1px 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You are for sure facing subpixel rendring issue since you are defining very small circles having less than `1px` radius. If you increase the values you will see something on Firefox:

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F8F9FA;
  background-image: 
    /* doesn't matter what you put here as value since the background-size is already small */
    radial-gradient(#dedede 51px, transparent 51px), 
    radial-gradient(#dedede 50px, transparent 50px), 
    radial-gradient(#dedede 99px, transparent 5px), 
    radial-gradient(#dedede 54px, transparent 54px);
  background-position: top, right, bottom, left;
  background-size: 1px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```